# Java stream: Grouping HashMap key values to prevent duplicate keys

Tags: java, stream, hashmap, java-stream

I have the following HashMap in my Java app:

```
final Map<UUID, Boolean> map = demoRepo.demoService.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                ProductDTO::getMenuUuid,
                ProductDTO::getStatus));
```

However, as the result contains multiple `menuUuid` value, I need to group them as the key does not contain the same value. So, how should I do this using stream?

**Update:** I also tried `groupingBy` as shown below, but I think the usage is not correct:

```
final Map<UUID, Boolean> map = sdemoRepo.demoService.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        ProductDTO::getMenuUuid, LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(ProductDTO::getStatus)));
```

Suppose that I have the following stream:

```
MenuUuid   |   Status |
-----------------------
1              true
2              false
1              true
1              true
3              true
2              false
```

Then I need a map result like; 1:true, 2:false, 3:true

Comment: Use `Collectors.groupIngBy` instead of `Collectors.toMap`.

Comment: What are you grouping exactly?  Can you show an example of what you want to see?

Comment: `groupingBy` will produce a `Map<UUID, List<Boolean>>` unless you use some reducing collector. How should your end result look like?

Comment: @harry  Do you want the `boolean` to reflect all are true for a given id or at least one is true.

Comment: @Eritrean Yes, you right. I need a single result as I mentioned on Update like; 1:true, 2:false, 3:true

Comment: @WJS Did you look at my update? I just want to prevent duplication, otherwise all the products with the same UUID has the same boolean value. I just need to use their UUID value at once as it is key value.

Comment: What if two key-value pairs exist with same key and different values, for example `1, true` and `1, false` which one do you want to keep and why?

Comment: @Eritrean  See his comment to me above.  I addressed this in my answer as there is no need for a logical operation if they are all one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the user ids have the same boolean then just do the following:

```
final Map<UUID, Boolean> map = demoRepo.demoService.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                ProductDTO::getMenuUuid,
                ProductDTO::getStatus,
                (existingValue, newValue)->existingValue));
```

the last lambda, is a merge function. it is used to make a decision on how to merge duplicate keys.  In this case, it just keeps the first that's already there.  You could also use the new one since you aren't really altering the `boolean` and they are all the same value.

If your `ProductDTO` class uses `UUID` to determine equality via `equals()` you could also do the following:

```
final Map<UUID, Boolean> map = demoRepo.demoService.stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                ProductDTO::getMenuUuid,
                ProductDTO::getStatus));
```

This works because you won't have any duplicate UUID's

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying and inform you. I remember merge function. As far as I see, merge function is used to prevent the same value to be a key value of HashMap by a filter condition? Is that true?

Comment: Not really a filter.  If a second value with the same key is encountered it simply specifies a way to handle it.  Like concatenating strings.  But it can also be used to keep the first or the last encountered.  Which in  your case doesn't make any difference.  So I would suggest just keeping the first.

Answer (score 0):

The [Collectors.toMap(Function keyMapper,
Function valueMapper,
BinaryOperator mergeFunction)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) allows the caller to define a [BinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) mergeFunction that returns the correct value if the stream provides a key-value pair for a key that already exists.

The following example uses the Boolean.logicalOr method to combine the existing value with the new one.
Equal UUID keys are not grouped,since the result is a single key-single value map. But

```
final Map<UUID, Boolean> map = demoRepo.demoService.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                ProductDTO::getMenuUuid,
                ProductDTO::getStatus,
                 Boolean::logicalOr));
```

In particular `Boolean::logicalOr` is a function that is called if the map already contains a value for the key. In this case, the `Boolean::logicalOr takes as argument the existing map value and  the new value from the` Stream` and returns the Logical Or of these two, as the result. This results is then entered in the map.

Comment: What does the last line do? Could you explain? And is it better to use `Collectors.groupIngBy` ?

Comment: This version of `toMap` uses the last function (`||` or `&&`) to combine any values that have the same key.

Comment: @harry I have updated the answer after your comment with some explanation of what the last line does. An important question if you need to use a Map is to define what should happen when a key value pair is encountered multiple times. Otherwise a different data structure might be better.

Comment: What do you mean with another structure instead of map? Do you mean List, or LinkedList, etc?

Comment: By the way voted up amigo ;)

Comment: For instance a MultiValueMap https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html where you can have many values for a single key.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to merge the values. See if it helps

```
final Map<UUID, Boolean> map  =
    demoRepo.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                ProductDTO::getMenuUuid,
                ProductDTO::getStatus,
                (menuUuid, status) -> {
                  menuUuid.addAll(status);
                  return menuUuid;
                }));
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems to be increasing unnecessary code. May it be better to use `Collectors.groupIngBy` ?